# Css3 несколько фонов

Tags: css, css3

Проблема: я назначаю один фон в css, а второй надо сделать inline в элементе. И выходит, что второй фон перекрывает первый, а мне надо, чтобы они были одновременно. Как это сделать?

Comment: Прописать оба фона в inline-стилях.

Comment: это решает проблему, но я в :hover еще меняю фон. А псевдоклассов в inline насколько я знаю, нету.

Comment: @SPAHI4, а что мешает вместо inline-стилей добавлять еще 1 класс, а потом селектором **.class1.class2** выбирать нужный элемент и добавлять второй фон?

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняй в пнг с прозрачностью, и вставляй. Что бы менять положение по вертикали используй - `z-index` + `position: relative;`

Comment: я не про это. перекрывает не в смысле заслоняет собой - он у меня полупрозрачный, а заменяет значение фона собой.

Comment: создаёшь отдельный div внутри певрого элемента, основного бекграунда. И ему приписываешь свой бекграунд.